# How to introspect function & macro arguments in elisp?

Tags: functions, help, arguments

Is there a programmatic way to access function/macro arguments,

Something like this, which returns the the arg count and true if it accepts any number of additional arguments.

eg:

- `(number-of-arguments-and-rest "if")` -> `'(2, t)`
- `(number-of-arguments-and-rest "progn")` -> `'(0, t)`
- `(number-of-arguments-and-rest "null")` -> `'(1, nil)`

Comment: Note: the right answer is usually "yes there is but it won't reliably do what you need".  IOW it's an XY problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `func-arity` added in 26.1. `C-h f func-arity`:

> func-arity is a built-in function in `C source code'.
>
> ```
> (func-arity FUNCTION)
> ```
>
> Return minimum and maximum number of args allowed for FUNCTION.
>   FUNCTION must be a function of some kind.
>   The returned value is a cons
>   cell `(MIN . MAX)`.
>   `MIN` is the minimum number of args.
>   `MAX` is the
>   maximum number, or the symbol `many`, for a function with `&rest`
>   args, or `unevalled` for a special form.

For example,

```
(func-arity 'null)
;; => (1 . 1)

(func-arity 'if)
;; => (2 . unevalled)

(func-arity 'progn)
;; => (0 . unevalled)

(func-arity '+)
;; => (0 . many)
```

Comment: Be aware that the returned value can be misleading.  E.g. it may say `(2 . many)` when in reality it will fail when called with more than, say, 3 arguments.